# Помогите с разобраться с тестом)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напиши программу для принтера `make_stickers`, которая принимает число `details_count` и строку `robot_part`. Функция должна возвращать список строк в следующем формате: `{robot_part} detail #{n}`.

Примеры:

если `make_stickers(3, 'Body')` вернуть функция должна `['Body detail #1', 'Body detail #2', 'Body detail #3']`.

Задачка по теме списки.

Hачало функции:

```
def make_stickers(details_count: int, robot_part: str) -> list:
    # write you code here
```

пока что все до чего додумался это

```
 res = '[]'
    for i in range(details_count):
        n = i + 1
        res = f"[{robot_part} detail #{n}]"
        return res
    if details_count == 0:
        return res
```

но дает только 1 результат Получено:
[Hand detail #1]

Comment: конец функции `return res`

Comment: в чем конкретно у вас проблема? задача решается через цикл `for` и f-строку (так удобнее)

Comment: дополнил вопрос)

Comment: @KonungOlaf не обращайте внимание на комментарий. Это просто проверка условия получения секретной шляпы **Helping finger**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в формате строки и возвращаете вы неправильно, нужно вернуть список

Исправил:

```
def make_stickers(details_count: int, robot_part: str) -> list:
    items = []
    for i in range(details_count):
        items.append(f"{robot_part} detail #{i+1}")
    return items
```

В одну строку:

```
    return [f"{robot_part} detail #{i+1}" for i in range(details_count)]
```

Comment: огромное спасибо) а то только начинаю изучать)

Comment: @KonungOlaf, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 res = '[]'
    for i in range(details_count):
        n = i + 1
        res = f"[{robot_part} detail #{n}]"
        return res
    if details_count == 0:
        return res
```

1. вы не пополняете список каждый цикл, а создаете новый, на пополнения надо использовать метод `append`
2. у вас `return` в цикле стоит, а значит будет выполнен только 1 цикл, вместо всех
3. ну и проверку на 0 можно не делать, ведь при `details_count = 0` цикл и так не будет выполняться
4. зачем в строке вы пишете `[]`? В примере такого нет

Так что исходя из этого:

```
    res = []
    for i in range(details_count):
        n = i + 1
        res.append(f"{robot_part} detail #{n}")
    return res
```

Из оптимизаций - зачем вводить дополнительную переменную `n`, когда можно все сделать внутри f-строки:

```
    res = []
    for i in range(details_count):
        res.append(f"[{robot_part} detail #{i + 1}]")
    return res
```

Ну и вообще все можно сделать в 1 строчку

```
    res = [f"{robot_part} detail #{i + 1} for i in range(details_count)"]
```